# Converting PHP regex to Java

Tags: java, php, regex

Im trying to convert the following PHP code to java:

```
$type=explode("] [", preg_replace("#^\s*\[|\]\s*$#","", $_POST['var']));
```

I came up with java equivalent:

```
String[] subjectArr=var.replaceAll("#^\s*\[|\]\s*$#", "").split("] [");
```

The regex suppose to strip the first and last brackets from this sample string: [ALL] [type] [peter] to ALL] [type] [peter after which the ] [ will be removed. But I'm getting errors, anyone could translate this regex?

Comment: `.replaceAll("^\\s*\\[|]\\s*$", "").split("]\\s+\\[")`

Comment: As @WiktorStribiżew showed but didn't explain, ``\`` is an escape character in Java literals, so it must itself be escaped, i.e. doubled: ``\`` -> ``\\``. --- Also, `split()` takes a regex, and `[` is a special character in a regex, so it must be escaped, and again the ``\`` must be escaped in a Java literal, so ``[`` -> ``\[`` -> ``\\[``. --- Instead of escaping it, you could also quote it: `split(Pattern.quote("] ["))`